# Javascript: Getting around using a global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, global-variables

I have an ajax call that is fired by a keyboard handler and returns a jsonObj (I'm currently storing it a global variable), and this ajax call finishes to completion right away.  Then, if a user does a mouse click, another event handler function is called.  However, this mouse event handler will need to get hold of that json object that was created by the other function. [See Code below]

```
var $jsonObj;


function makeAjaxCall() {
   $jsonObj;  //do ajax call
   ...
}

function updateInformation(text) {
   //use $jsonObj here
}

function mouseClickHandler(e) {
   updateInformation(text);
   ...
}

function  keydownHandler(e) {
   makeAjaxCall();
   updateInformation(text);
   ...
}

addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClickHandler, false);
addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);
```

[According to this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133100/javascript-variable-scope-the-evils-of-globals/10133133#10133133), sticking everything in one giant function should do the trick.  I'm wondering what other elegant ways are out there? Or is using global the more elegant approach here?

P.S.  [Here's what the flow looks like in a diagram to see my thought process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTS6c.jpg)

Comment: As you have read using a closure or IIFE (or the "one giant function") is the cleanest solution. So basically your variable is at the scope of that function. Closure are good pratice and I would suggest the first line inside it to be "use strict"; to enable javascript strict mode where available.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are the only thing in javascript that created isolated scopes.

You should not pollute the global scope with your own objects / functions.

You are correct that wrapping your code in a giant function would solve your problem.

```
(function(){
    //Put all your code here
}());
```

This is a self executing anonymous function which will execute at once when the javascript is executed.

If you need to pass in dependencies to be used with your code you can do it like this.

```
(function(param1, param2){
    //Put all your code here
}(arg1, arg));
```

Example:

```
(function(jQuery){
    var $ = jQuery;

    $("#target").mousedown(function() {
        updateInformation($(this).text());
        ...
    });

    $("#target").keydown(function() {
        $.getJSON("example.json")
        .done(function(data) {
            updateInformation(data.text);
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        });
    });
}($));
```

Comment: self executing anonymous function -- the term [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043779/understanding-iife-immediately-invoked-function-expressions) is better.

Answer (score 0):

> sticking everything in one giant function should do the trick

Yes, you need to stick everything that wants to access `$jsonObj` in the same scope (function).

> I'm wondering what other elegant ways are out there?

You don't have to stick *everything* in that scope. `makeAjaxCall` and `updateInformation` might as well stay global when they are loosely coupled enough - i.e. taking that object as an argument or returning it to the caller.

> Or is using global the more elegant approach here?

That's hardly ever a good solution.